# Get values of conditionals from different columns in dataframe (tried pivottable)

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, formatting, pivot-table

I want to essentially make a pivot table but have it sorted very specifically. For example I want it to calculate the mean when Var2=C|Var3=2 and Var4=0. Wasn't sure how to incorporate 'or' or 'and' intot he pivottable function. Put an example table below for the input and outputs:

Input:

| Entry | Data | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | C | 3 | 0 | B |
| B | 1 | A | 2 | 1 | B |
| C | 2 | B | 1 | 1 | B |
| D | 2 | C | 3 | 0 | A |
| E | 3 | B | 2 | 0 | C |
| F | 3 | B | 1 | 1 | A |
| G | 4 | A | 3 | 0 | A |
| H | 4 | C | 2 | 0 | C |

Output:
Averages

| Avg | Var3=3 or Var3=2 | Var2=B | Var2=A or Var5=B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var4=0 | 2.8 | 3 | 2.5 |
| Var4=1 | 1 | 2.5 | 1.5 |

Medians

| Med | Var3=3 or Var3=2 | Var2=B | Var2=A or Var5=B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var4=0 | 3 | 3 | 2.5 |
| Var4=1 | 1 | 2.5 | 1.5 |

Tried this to sort specific values, but it doesn't really do the same thing that I want:
[Python Pandas Dataframe Pivot Table Column and Values Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69762822/python-pandas-dataframe-pivot-table-column-and-values-order)
Was looking more for the 'or' function to pivot on multiple conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def my_func(g):
    avg_1 = g.query("Var3 == 3 or Var3 == 2")["Data"].mean()
    avg_2 = g.query("Var2 == 'B'")["Data"].mean()
    avg_3 = g.query("Var2 == 'A' or Var5 == 'B'")["Data"].mean()

    med_1 = g.query("Var3 == 3 or Var3 == 2")["Data"].median()
    med_2 = g.query("Var2 == 'B'")["Data"].median()
    med_3 = g.query("Var2 == 'A' or Var5 == 'B'")["Data"].median()

    return pd.Series(
        [avg_1, avg_2, avg_3, med_1, med_2, med_3],
        index=["Avg1", "Avg2", "Avg3", "Med1", "Med2", "Med3"],
    )


out = df.groupby("Var4").apply(my_func)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
      Avg1  Avg2  Avg3  Med1  Med2  Med3
Var4                                    
0      2.8   3.0   2.5   3.0   3.0   2.5
1      1.0   2.5   1.5   1.0   2.5   1.5
```